# Newer version of cmake available in CentOS 7 than in CentOS 8?

Tags: cmake, centos, yum

I have CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 installed on 2 VMs. Both have `epel` enabled.

**CentOS 7:**

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

$ yum repolist
...
repo id                                                                                              repo name                                                                                                                          status
base/7/x86_64                                                                                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                                    10070
epel/x86_64                                                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                                     13445
extras/7/x86_64                                                                                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                                    413
updates/7/x86_64                                                                                     CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                                  1127
repolist: 25055
```

**CentOS 8:**

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) 

$ yum repolist
repo id                                                                                           repo name
AppStream                                                                                         CentOS-8 - AppStream
BaseOS                                                                                            CentOS-8 - Base
PowerTools                                                                                        CentOS-8 - PowerTools
epel                                                                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras                                                                                            CentOS-8 - Extras
```

On `CentOS 7`, `cmake3` is available from the `epel` repo, and provides cmake version 3.17.

```
$ yum provides cmake3
...
cmake3-3.17.3-3.el7.x86_64 : Cross-platform make system
Repo        : epel
```

On `CentOS 8`, `cmake3` is available from the `AppStream` repo, and provides cmake version 3.11.

```
$ yum provides cmake3
...
cmake-3.11.4-7.el8.x86_64 : Cross-platform make system
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : cmake3 = 3.11.4-7.el8
```

I tried to disable all repos except for `epel`, but it's still coming back with the one from `AppStream` (which seems counter intuitive to me - surely it should come back with nothing if I've disabled all the other repos?)

```
$ yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=epel info cmake
Last metadata expiration check: 0:21:06 ago on Fri 11 Sep 2020 09:44:08 AM UTC.
Installed Packages
Name         : cmake
Version      : 3.11.4
Release      : 7.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 24 M
Source       : cmake-3.11.4-7.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : AppStream
Summary      : Cross-platform make system
URL          : http://www.cmake.org
License      : BSD and MIT and zlib
Description  : CMake is used to control the software compilation process using simple
             : platform and compiler independent configuration files. CMake generates
             : native makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler
             : environment of your choice. CMake is quite sophisticated: it is possible
             : to support complex environments requiring system configuration, preprocessor
             : generation, code generation, and template instantiation.
```

I searched on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=cmake), and it certainly does seem that `cmake-3.11` is the latest version available to `CentOS 8`.

Apart from building from source, is there any other way to obtain a newer version of `cmake` on `CentOD 8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmake: 3.11.4` version will still be listed when you run `yum info` because it is *already installed*, so disabling the AppStream repo won't affect what is shown. If you *only* want to show **available** packages (based on your enabled yum repos), you can run this instead:

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=epel info cmake --available
```

---

If you want to install the latest version of CMake (or some other version), you can always download the binary distribution from the CMake [download page](https://cmake.org/download/).

Once downloaded, you can extract the package to somewhere you have access to on your machine, e.g.:

```
mkdir ~/cmake
tar xvzf ~/Downloads/cmake-3.18.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C ~/cmake
```

Finally, make sure you add the extracted `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable so you can run the `cmake` executable from the command line.